# Android SDK location not set after env. variable setting in Jenkinsfile pipeline

Tags: android, flutter, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to set up some Jenkins CI/CD pipeline for a mobile application written with Flutter. At the moment, I am only concerned with the Android part. So far, I have managed to have all the tooling installed but somehow when running the last step, `flutter build apk --release`, my pipeline fails and complains about `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` not being set even though I have explicitly set it.

Here is my Jenkins pipeline :

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'xxx/my-flutter-agent:0.6'
    }
  }

  environment {
    ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/var/home_jenkins/Android/sdk
  }

  stages {
    stage('Building') {
      steps {
        echo "Building Flutter release"
        sh 'flutter channel stable'
        sh 'flutter upgrade --force'
        sh 'flutter doctor -v'
        sh 'flutter pub get'
        sh 'flutter build apk --release'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First of all, `flutter doctor` complained about the SDK not being installed.

```
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.
```

but of course, I have it installed at the path specified in the `environment` block. I then tried to set the config with `flutter config --android-sdk /var/home_jenkins/Android/sdk`, it did not work.

```
+ flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in mobile-flutter...                     24.7s
[Pipeline] sh
+ ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/var/jenkins_home/Android/sdk
+ flutter build apk --release
[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
```

Is there something I am missing regarding the setting of the environment variable ?

Comment: Can you share the SDK information from the `Dockerfile` for `xxx/my-flutter-agent:0.6`?

Comment: my bad @MattSchuchard it was actually a misconfiguration on my volumes and I totally forgot to answer this question. Sorry for that. Thanks a lot anyway.